# Python3: Can't delete items from list; can't slice elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list I created from the names of excel workbook sheets:

```
file = 'Per_6_PL.xlsx'
wb = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheet_list = [wb.sheet_names]
```

I can see this is a list by the following code:

```
type(sheet_list)
list
```

I want to drop the first element of the list and use the others to build a loop.
When I try to delete the first element of the list, either through `del` or `.remove` methods, it deletes the entire list. .

```
del sheet_list[0]

sheet_list
[]
```

Additionally, I can't slice elements from the list, as I get the entire list returned:

```
sheet_list[0:3]

[['Table of Contents',
  '07',
  '01',
  '01.01',
  '13',
  '13.01',
  '3002',
  '3005',
  '3003',
  '3004',
```

...

I'm not sure what's happening here. I'm fairly new to Python and can't understand what is causing this behavior. I want a list of all sheet names with the first element omitted. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `sheet_list` is a list containing a single list of names, not a copy of the contents of `wb.sheet_names`.

Comment: I suppose that's why when it printed the list contents, it has double square brackets?

Comment: @jules325 exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You load the data as a nested list. as per **ALollz** comment below:

`sheet_list = [wb.sheet_names]` loads the data contained in in `wb.sheet_names` into a list, as specified when you wrap it in hard brackets ("[","]"). That means you load the list data of `wb.sheet_names` into another list, nesting them. Load it as
`sheet_list = wb.sheet_names` and your script will work without changes.

Comment: Really, they should just do `sheet_list = wb.sheet_names` instead of creating a list of lists, then un-nesting it.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, missed that it was loaded in a list. Good point. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks very much. @ALollz So, wb.sheet_names returns a list, and then I was embedding that list in a list?

Comment: @jules325 That's right. By putting brackets around it, you basically said "I want this (the list of sheet names) to be in a list, please!"

Answer (score 2):

Your list is actually a 2-dimensional list. Each element of the list is a list of sheet names. So when you delete the first item of `sheet_list`, you're actually deleting the entire list.

To make `sheet_list` just contain the sheet names in a single list, use the following code:

```
file = 'Per_6_PL.xlsx'
wb = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheet_list = wb.sheet_names
```

Then, to delete the "Table of Contents":

```
del sheet_list[0]
sheet_list
[ '07',
  '01',
  '01.01',
  '13',
  '13.01',
  '3002',
  '3005',
  '3003',
  '3004',
...
```